# WordPress: Custom date calculator function only working for the 21st day of each month

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am developing a simple day calculator WordPress plugin for property sales. The point of the application is to give the user the 45th & 180th day after they close on their property.

The calculation converts Datetime to Epoch time and then adds 45/180 days worth of ticks and then converts the sums back into datetime. I figured this would be the best way to work around things such as leap years.

I got the PHP and basic HTML form working locally with no issues. However when I added the code to work inside a WordPress plugin I found that the calculator only works when the 21st of each month is selected. If any other date is selected I get a 404 error. Not exactly sure why this could be happening.

Here is a link to the plugin code https://github.com/Anth0nyBarb0sa/Days-Calculator-Plugin the code below is what I had running on localhost without any issues.

If you want to check out the plugin in action I created a test page on my website https://anthonybarbosadevelopment.com/test-page

```
<?php
//Return Name of Month
function getMonth($date)
{
    switch ($date) {
        case 1:
            $month = 'January';
            break;
        case 2:
            $month = 'Febuary';
            break;
        case 3:
            $month = 'March';
            break;
        case 4:
            $month = 'April';
            break;
        case 5:
            $month = 'May';
            break;
        case 6:
            $month = 'June';
            break;
        case 7:
            $month = 'July';
            break;
        case 8:
            $month = 'August';
            break;
        case 9:
            $month = 'September';
            break;
        case 10:
            $month = 'October';
            break;
        case 11:
            $month = 'November';
            break;
        case 12:
            $month = 'December';
            break;
        default:
            $month = 'Not a valid month!';
            break;
    }
    return $month;
}

//Initialize years 1 year behind and 4 years in advance
$yearCurrent = date('Y', time());
$yearBefore = $yearCurrent - 1;
$year1 = $yearCurrent + 1;
$year2 = $yearCurrent + 2;
$year3 = $yearCurrent + 3;
$year4 = $yearCurrent + 4;


//Initalize results
$dateTimeMSG = "";
$fourtyfiveMSG = "";
$oneeightyMSG = "";
$dateTime = "";
$fourtyfive = "";
$oneeighty = "";
if (isset($_GET['run'])) {

    //initalize selected date
    $month = $_GET['month'];
    $day = $_GET['day'];
    $year = $_GET['year'];

    //Other
    $seconds = 86400;

    try {
        //Convert to unix timestamp
        $dateTime = new DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-{$day}");
        $dateTime = $dateTime->format('U');

        //Add 45 days
        $fourtyfive = $dateTime + ($seconds * 45);
        //Add 180 days
        $oneeighty = $dateTime + ($seconds * 180);

        //Convert to date time
        function getWeekDay($date)
        {
            $weekday = date('N', $date);
            switch ($weekday) {
                case 1:
                    $weekday = "Monday";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $weekday = "Tuesday";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $weekday = "Wednesday";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $weekday = "Thursday";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $weekday = "Friday";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $weekday = "Saturday";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    $weekday = "Sunday";
                    break;
                default:
                    $weekday = "Not a valid Day!";
            }
            return $weekday;
        }
        function getDateTime($dateTime)
        {
            $weekday = getWeekDay($dateTime); // 1-7
            $month = getMonth(gmdate("m", $dateTime));
            $day = gmdate("d", $dateTime);
            $year = gmdate("Y", $dateTime);
            $dateTime = "{$weekday}, {$month} {$day}, {$year}";
            return $dateTime;
        }

        $dateTime = getDateTime(($dateTime));
        $fourtyfive = getDateTime(($fourtyfive));
        $oneeighty = getDateTime(($oneeighty));

        //Format to Message
        $dateTimeMSG = "For <strong>{$dateTime}</strong>";
        $fourtyfiveMSG = "Your 45-day Identification Period ends on midnight of: <strong>{$fourtyfive}</strong>";
        $oneeightyMSG = "Your 180-day Identification Period ends on midnight of: <strong>{$oneeighty}</strong>";
        $disclaimer1 = "<strong>Always verify your exchange deadlines with your tax advisor.</strong>";
        $disclaimer2 = "<strong>Notice: </strong>The actual deadline for completing an exchange is the earlier of either 180 days from the date on which the Exchanger transfers the relinquished property, or the due date, including extensions filed by the Exchanger, for the Exchanger's tax return for the year of the transfer of the relinquished property. Consult your tax advisor regarding your tax filing requirement dates.";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $dateTimeMSG = "";
        $fourtyfiveMSG = "";
        $oneeightyMSG = "";
        $dateTime = "";
        $fourtyfive = "";
        $oneeighty = "";
        $disclaimer1 = "";
        $disclaimer2 = "";
    }
}


?>

<html>



<body>
    <div id="calculator">
        <div>
            <p>Date the relinquished property (sale) was closed:</p>
            <form class="days-form" action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="get">
                <div>
                    <label for="month">Month:</label>
                    <select type="select" name="month" id="month">
                        <option value="<?php echo 1; ?>">January</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 2; ?>">February</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 3; ?>">March</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 4; ?>">April</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 5; ?>">May</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 6; ?>">June</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 7; ?>">July</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 8; ?>">August</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 9; ?>">September</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 10; ?>">October</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 11; ?>">November</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 12; ?>">December</option>
                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById('month').value = "<?php echo $_GET['month']; ?>";
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="day">Day:</label>
                    <select type="select" name="day" id="day">
                        <option value="<?php echo 1; ?>">1</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 2; ?>">2</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 3; ?>">3</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 4; ?>">4</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 5; ?>">5</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 6; ?>">6</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 7; ?>">7</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 8; ?>">8</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 9; ?>">9</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 10; ?>">10</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 11; ?>">11</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 12; ?>">12</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 13; ?>">13</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 14; ?>">14</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 15; ?>">15</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 16; ?>">16</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 17; ?>">17</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 18; ?>">18</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 19; ?>">19</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 20; ?>">20</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 21; ?>">21</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 22; ?>">22</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 23; ?>">23</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 24; ?>">24</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 25; ?>">25</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 26; ?>">26</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 27; ?>">27</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 28; ?>">28</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 29; ?>">29</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 30; ?>">30</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo 31; ?>">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById('day').value = "<?php echo $_GET['day']; ?>";
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for="year">Year:</label>
                    <select type="select" name="year" id="year">
                        <option value="<?= $yearBefore ?>"><?= $yearBefore ?></option>
                        <option value="<?= $yearCurrent ?>"><?= $yearCurrent ?></option>
                        <option value="<?= $year1 ?>"><?= $year1 ?></option>
                        <option value="<?= $year2 ?>"><?= $year2 ?></option>
                        <option value="<?= $year3 ?>"><?= $year3 ?></option>
                        <option value="<?= $year4 ?>"><?= $year4 ?></option>
                    </select>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.getElementById('year').value = "<?php echo $_GET['year']; ?>";
                    </script>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" name="run">Submit</button>

                <div>
                    <p><?= $dateTimeMSG ?></p>
                    <p><?= $fourtyfiveMSG ?></p>
                    <p><?= $oneeightyMSG ?></p>
                    <p><?= $disclaimer1 ?></p>
                    <p><?= $disclaimer2 ?></p>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting an error just on the 21st but I can say your code is quite overcomplicated for what you're trying to do and you'd benefit from simplifying it. I recommend reading the PHP docs for [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) and learning the features there. All of the validation and conversion functionality you've written here is already built into those native PHP functions, so you don't need 95% of this code, and I'll wager that eliminating it will resolve your issue. Note three important things:

- If you provide an invalid date string to `strtotime()` or `DateTime`, you'll get an error -- so you don't have to explicitly check for valid values before you make those calls.
- The built-in formatters like `DateTime::format()` will output anything you need, so you don't need to convert numbers to month names or weekdays yourself.
- Relative strings like `"2022-01-01 +45 days"` are understood by `strtotime()` and `DateTime`. This is a super handy feature, there's no need to manually do this math.

So, pretty much all of your calculations can be replaced by:

```
// Given $date contains a string in YYYY-MM-DD format:
try {
    $d45 = (new DateTime("$date +45 days"))->format('D, M d, Y');
    $d180 = (new DateTime("$date +180 days"))->format('D, M d, Y');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // bad date provided
}
```

This yields:

```
string(17) "Tue, Feb 15, 2022"
string(17) "Thu, Jun 30, 2022"
```

I'd also recommend that you use [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) instead of three separate pull-downs, as it will be rendered nicely as a calendar selector in modern browsers.